# autowiring byName in spring

Tags: spring

I am just starting up with Spring and trying autowiring byName
here is my code

Address class:

```java
package org.springinaction;

public class Address {
    private String addressline;

    public String getAddressline() {
        return addressline;
    }

    public void setAddressline(String addressline) {
        this.addressline = addressline;
    }

}
```

Customer class:

```java
package org.springinaction;

public class Customer {
    private Address address;
    public Address getN() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setN(Address n) {
        this.address = n;
    }
}
```

Spring cofiguration:

```xml
<beans>
  <bean id="customer" class="org.springinaction.Customer" autowire="byName" />

  <bean id="address" class="org.springinaction.Address">
    <property name="addressline" value="bangalore" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

CustomerTest.java

```java
package org.springinaction;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class CustomerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringInAction.xml");
        Customer cust=(Customer)context.getBean("customer");
        System.out.println(cust.getN());
    }
}
```

When I am trying to do autowring by name which states thats if name of property matches with name of name it will get autowired.however in my case its not happening.
its giving me null with this...can anyone help me this this so that it be autowired correctly

Comment: (Please indent your code for readability.)

Comment: hi I did according to the recommendation from the website...is the code not clear???

Comment: thanks i was not aware about it...

Comment: `matches with name of name` what do you mean? and where is the bean named(with id) `"n"`? Your property is named `'n'` according to Java Beans standard which Spring adheres to.

Comment: @user728907 "Indentation" means using whitespace to indicate code structure and layout.

Answer (score 2):

The "name" that auto wiring looks for is the name of the JavaBean property as derived from the name of the setter method, therefore your Customer class has a property named `n` (from the `setN` method), the fact that the private field is named `address` is irrelevant.

You either need to define a suitable bean with id `n` or change the getter and setter in Customer to `getAddress` and `setAddress` in order to match the name of the existing `address` bean.

Answer (score 1):

Change your getter and setter to this:

```
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address n) {
    this.address = n;
}
```

According to [Java beans convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/index.html) your getter and setter must have name **get (or set) + name of property with first letter capitalized**.

Comment: i did that but nothing has changed same null....if we change the property of customer class from address to lets say street autowiring will not happen...am i right???

Comment: does it depend on sames on getter and setter methods also??

Comment: Please read the link I provided. Everything is in that small tutorial, especially [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your Customer bean to be injected with your Address bean, then simply use the @Autowired annotation, no need for setters/getters then:

```
<context:annotation-config /> // EDIT - think this required for autowiring

<bean id="customer" class="org.springinaction.Customer"/>

<bean id="address" class="org.springinaction.Address">
    <property name="addressline" value="bangalore" />
</bean>

public class Customer {
    @Autowired
    Address address;
....
```

Have more than 1 address bean? Then use the @Qualifier as well:

```
<bean id="customer" class="org.springinaction.Customer"/>

<bean id="work-address" class="org.springinaction.Address">
    <property name="addressline" value="bangalore" />
</bean>

<bean id="home-address" class="org.springinaction.Address">
    <property name="addressline" value="bangalore" />
</bean>

public class Customer {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier ( value = "work-address" )
    Address workAddress;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier ( value = "home-address" )
    Address homeAddress;
....
```